# SQL - Date Query Issue - varchar to datetime conversion resulted in out-of-range value

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query written by a colleague who is no longer here. The query runs as part of an SSIS job, and as of this month has started failing with the following error:

> *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

The query itself is just a basic select with a where clause that looks for values in a certain time range (the date range between `@startdate` and `@enddate`)

The code to determine the time range is below:

```
DECLARE     @RunDateTime datetime
DECLARE     @RunDate datetime
DECLARE     @StartDate datetime
DECLARE     @EndDate datetime
DECLARE     @Month int
DECLARE     @Year int
DECLARE     @strStartDate varchar(10)

SET     @RunDateTime = GetDate()
SET     @RunDate = cast(round(convert(real, @RunDateTime),0,1) as datetime)

IF                  DATEPART(d, @RunDate) = 16
    BEGIN       
                    SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(d, -15, @RunDate)
                    SET @EndDate = @RunDate
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
                    IF      Month(@RunDate) = 1
                            SET @Month = 12
                    ELSE    
                            SET @Month = Month(@RunDate) - 1

                    IF      Month(@RunDate) = 1
                            SET @Year = Year(@RunDate) - 1
                    ELSE
                            SET @Year = Year(@RunDate)

                    SET @strStartDate = CONVERT(varchar(2), @Month)+ '/16/' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @Year)
                    SET @StartDate = CONVERT(datetime, @strStartDate, 101)
                    SET @EndDate = @RunDate
    END
```

This job runs twice a month. Once on the 16th for data from the 1st to the 15th of the month, and once on the 1st of the next month for data from the 16th to the end of the previous month.

From what I can find online, the use of the `varchar` for `strStartDate` is the likely culprit?  I'm not familiar enough with SQL to know how to replace all that convert stuff that's going on there?  Also, is there a better way to determine the end of the month date than just getting the run time?  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

(PS, we run this job on SQL Server 2008 R2)  And I checked with the DBA and he said nothing about localization or regional settings has changed on the SQL server.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to calculate the 16th of last month. Rather than doing string manipulation, try `SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@RunDate),'20001216')`, which should always find it (keep the two string constants exactly as they are).

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the section of code you posted? The 101 on the line CONVERT(datetime, @strStartDate, 101) indicates that strStartDate should be in the mm/dd/yyyy format , which it is, so that shouldn't be dependant on the regional settings of the Server.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, this query will always be run on the 1st and the 16th of a month.  If it's not run on the 16th of a month, it must be the 1st, so then we want the StartDate value to represent the 16th of the previous month. (We basically just want to get day #16 of the previous month if the query is run on the 1st)

I'm not so SQL literate, but does that code you provided work for any month?  Or just do for December?

Comment: @sgmoore I am by no means positive, but the rest of the query is 

SELECT name, startdate, jobid

WHERE startdate BETWEEN @ StartDate AND @ EndDate

Comment: @Oryx - yes, it works for any month. Basically, it counts how many months have occurred between 1st January 2001 and `@RunDate`. It then adds that same number of months onto 16th December 2000. Which, if you think about it, should always produce the 16th of the month before `@RunDate`.

Comment: The only way the rest of the query could go wrong is if startdate is type varchar and has invalid values. If you have access to run sql queries directly, I would try running  `SELECT Count(*) from xxx WHERE startdate BETWEEN '20121216' and '20130101' `to see if it generates the error. Also you could run the section of code about and add a few selects eg, `Select  @strStartDate`  and `select @StartDate` to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependant** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Also: with SQL Server 2008, it is recommended to use `DATETIME2` (instead of `DATETIME`) if at all ever possible. `DATETIME2` parsing of strings is a lot more forgiving for error and/or different formats (like US AM/PM formatting etc.) .

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer.  I am working on reading through the links, but I guess I'm not so sure of the practical side of how to modify the SQL I posted.  Do I just change the strStartDateTime parameter to a datetime2?  If so, do I have to redo the logic for finding the 16th of the month since it seems to depend on that parameter being a varchar?  Sorry if these are dumb ?s

Comment: @Oryx: if you need to construct a string to be parsed into a `DATETIME`, I would just make sure to use one of the **safe** formats - so replace this: `SET @strStartDate = CONVERT(varchar(2), @Month)+ '/16/' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @Year)` with something like this: `YYYYMM16` and then convert - that's a safe and language-independent format which will always convert just fine.

Comment: @Oryx: if you need to construct string representations of dates, use the safe formats, e.g. construct `20130116` for the 16th of Jan 2013 - and then parse that. This will get converted to a `DATETIME` (or `DATE` or `DATETIME2`) on any installation of SQL Server, with any language and/or date format setting - no matter what.

Comment: Gotcha.  So if I wanted to construct a string to be converted to a DATETIME, would the following work:

Replace:

`SET @ strStartDate = CONVERT(varchar(2), @ Month)+ '/16/' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @ Year)`
`SET @ StartDate = CONVERT(datetime, @ strStartDate, 101)`

With:
`SET @ strStartDate = CAST(@ Year AS VARCHAR) + CAST(@ Month AS VARCHAR) + '16'`
`SET @ StartDate = CONVERT(datetime, @ strStartDate)'`

Comment: @Oryx: yes, that would be my recommendation for the easiest to achieve "win" in this situation. With this setup, your parsing of string-to-datetime ought to work all the time, regardless of settings on your SQL Server instance.

Comment: @marc_s: Not sure if you are aware: `YYYY-MM-DD` is a safe format [not only for `date` but also for `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1775 "SQL Fiddle demo").

Comment: @AndriyM: yes - that's true - unfortunately it's **NOT** safe for `DATETIME` (which most people still use....)